# SQL Server error 3417

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The message is

> The log scan number (1166:312:1) passed to log scan in database
>   'master' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that
>   the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error
>   occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise,
>   restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during
>   startup.

Can you help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Have you run `DBCC CHECKDB` on the master database?

Answer (score 1):

Restore your master database from a backup.  This is a good guide:

http://thomaslarock.com/2014/01/restore-the-master-database-in-sql-server-2012/

Answer (score -1):

First, run the DBCC CHECKDB command and find the exact reason behind this problem.Now restore from the updated backup. If you not have updated backup then try to fix the problem by using automatic repairing options of DBCC CHEKCDB:

- Repair Rebuild
- Repair allow data loss

Good Luck!

Comment: You need to stress the risks involved in the two DBCC CHECKDB options you suggest.